# How to check if an object StartDate is within the same current hour

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following code inside my razor view, and I need to display a word “New”, in case the StartDate of the object is equal to the current hour (added within one hour):-

I tried the following but the word New will not be displayed even if the object was just added:-

```
@if (item.StartDate.Value.Date == DateTime.Today)
{
    @item.StartDate.Value.ToString("h:mm tt")</span>
    <span class="green b"> 
      If (item.StartDate.Value.TimeOfDay.Hours == 
              DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay.Hours)
      {
          New !
      }
    </span>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check whether it is within the hour, then the following should work for you:

```
if (DateTime.Now - StartDate < TimeSpan.FromHours(1))
```

This assumes that StartDate has been set to `DateTime.Now` at the moment it is created and not `DateTime.Today`, because that would give you 00:00:00 for the time of day.

So for example:

```
<span>@item.StartDate.ToString("h:mm tt")</span>
@if (DateTime.Now - StartDate < TimeSpan.FromHours(1))
{
    <span class="green b">
        New !
    </span>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to output HTML:

```
If (item.StartDate.Value.TimeOfDay.Hours == DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay.Hours)
{
    <span class="green b">New !</span>
}
```

and get rid of those other `span` tags that are around the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<span class="green b"> 
If (item.StartDate.Value.TimeOfDay.Hours == DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay.Hours) 
{
   @:New !
}
</span>
```

You forgot to add `@:` to your code. You may use `<text></text>` as well.

A good reference about it: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to use DateTime.Now instead of DateTime.Today. The latter has hours, minutes and seconds set to zero. Also no need to call TimeOfDay, DateTime.Now.Hour is simpler.

Comment: Weird how other answers forgot about DateTime.Today and found other problems in your code :). Although, @Silvermind is right. If two DateTimes have the same Hour field, it doesn't mean that they are *within one hour*. For example, 13:59 and 14:01 are just two minutes apart, but their Hour fields are different.